# ¿Como puedo solucionar el error con "selectFile"?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var seleccion = new selectFile;
seleccion.targets('choose','selected');
```

```css
#fondo{
 text-transform: uppercase;
    color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
[value=Seleccionar]{
 background:black;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
    padding: 5px 12px;
  &:hover{
    background:black;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6" id=fondo>
<input  type=file hidden id=choose>
<input type=button onClick=seleccion.simulate() value=Seleccionar>
<label  id=selected>Ningún archivo seleccionado</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask] y 
[mre] y 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de responder, algunas recomendaciones acerca de buenas prácticas:

- Indenta tu código para facilitar la lectura
- Encierra entre comillas todos los valores de atributos para cada etiqueta, en vez de `id=choose` debe ser `id="choose"`. Referencia: [HTML Conceptos básicos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/HTML_basics)
- No incluyas eventos dentro de las etiquetas; evita el uso de `onclick="funcion()"`, en su lugar, asigna el evento desde Javascript
- Usa [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) para declarar variables

Ahora sí, vamos con la respuesta:

Tu código no funciona porque necesitas enlazar la librería `selectFile.js` y puedes obtenerla desde [este enlace](https://rawgit.com/thielicious/selectFile.js/master/selectFile.js) o buscar la versión más reciente en [GitHub](https://github.com/thielicious/selectFile.js), descargarla y enlazarla desde una ruta en tu proyecto; esta última opción es la más recomendable, porque [RawGit](https://rawgit.com/) es un proyecto abandonado y podría dejar de proporcionar acceso a los archivos.

```js
/* ***** Código de selectFile.js ***** */
const selectFile = function() {
    let regex = /[^\\]+$/
    this.choose,
    this.selected
    this.msg = str => {
        let prefix = '[selectFile.js]\n\nError: '
        return alert(prefix+str)
    }
    this.check = () => {
        if (this.choose && this.selected != null) {
            let choose = document.getElementById(this.choose),
                selected = document.getElementById(this.selected)
            choose.addEventListener('change',(e) => {
                if (choose.value != '') { 
                    selected.innerHTML = choose.value.match(regex)
                }
            })
        } else {
            this.msg('Targets not set.')
        }
    }
    selectFile.prototype.targets = (trigger, filetext) => {
        this.choose = trigger
        this.selected = filetext
    }
    selectFile.prototype.simulate = (e) => {
        if (this.choose != null) {
            let choose = document.getElementById(this.choose)
            if (typeof choose != 'undefined') {
                choose.click()
                this.check()
            } else {
                this.msg('Could not find element '+this.choose)
            }
        } else {
            this.msg('Targets not set.')
        }
    }   
};

// Inicializa la librería, declarando la variable con let
let seleccion = new selectFile();
// Asigna los contenedores (archivo y etiqueta)
seleccion.targets('choose','selected');
// Asigna el evento al botón, solo con el nombre de la función, sin paréntesis
document.querySelector('#seleccionar').addEventListener('click', seleccion.simulate);
```

```css
#fondo{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
#seleccionar {
     background:black;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
    padding: 5px 12px;
    &:hover{
        background:black;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6" id="fondo">
    <input type=file hidden id="choose">
    <button id="seleccionar">Seleccionar</button>
    <label id="selected" for="seleccionar">Ningún archivo seleccionado</label>
</div>

<button id="otro-boton">Otro botón</button>
```

Comment: Gracias ,pero ¿Cómo lo podría hacer sin esa librería?

Comment: @Lisseth, copia el código de esa librería y pégalo en un archivo .js de tu proyecto. Son solo unas pocas líneas.

Comment: Si ya lo realicé pero toma a todos los botones como file

Comment: @Lisseth, se me escapó una coma en lugar de punto al asignar el evento. Ya corregí el código, incluyendo aquí mismo la librería y otro botón para probar.

Comment: La no inclusión de eventos en etiquetas no debería ser una recomendación generalizada. La inyección de eventos implica agregar complejidad a la aplicación cuando se separa el comportamiento de la creación; las *Vistas Pasivas* tienen ventajas y desventajas, por lo que su implementación puede ser una decisión de arquitectura que dependerá mucho del contexto.

Comment: @Sal, muy respetable tu opinión, mas no la comparto, al menos para este caso específico, donde toda la lógica puede estar en un solo lugar.